# Math operators on linker script symbols

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

Titling this question was a bit difficult. But fundamentally I'm trying to perform a subtract operation using two address symbols defined by my linker script. Relevant section:

```
.text 0xffaa8000
{
    __text_start__ = .;
    *(.text*)
    __text_end__ = ALIGN(4);
}
```

The file using these address symbols is defined with an operation like the following:

```
.section .text
    ret
    ret
    ret

.quad __text_end__ - __text_start__
```

But when assembling (`gcc -c asm.S -o asm.o`) I get the following:

> `` asm.S:6: Error: can't resolve `__text_end__' {*UND* section} - `__text_start__' {*UND* section} ``

If there **is not a math operation** it works fine. That is, with such a file:

```
.section .text
    ret
    ret
    ret

.quad __text_end__
.quad __text_start__
```

---

So this makes sense. The symbols are external and if we don't know their value we obviously can't execute a subtraction on them. Can this be resolved by emitting relocations?

**EDIT**: Attempted to remove some irrelevant information that leaked into the initial question. In case someone else lands here with a similar issue.

Comment: ELF does not support relocations that reference more than one symbol, so this sort of computation is already out.  For the special case of the distance between a section beginning and end there might be a relocation type, but that depends on the architecture you are programming for.  Generally, the way to solve this is to move the computation into the linker script.

Comment: Hm. This must be true. The examples of code I’ve seen doing similar options seem to be operating on a locally (within the ASM file, `linker_sym - local_sym`) defined in the linker script. In this case it might work because the initial entry can be e.g. `-local_sym` with a relocation entry specifying to add the final address of `linker_sym`. Good to know.

Comment: Also I suppose you might be able to emit two or more relocations for the same address to have the desired effect if the feature was ever needed.

Comment: If you're using `gcc -c` then the linker isn't being run at all, and your linker script is irrelevant; this message is from the assembler.  I suppose it can only subtract two symbols whose (relative) addresses are known at assembly time, i.e. they are actually defined within your assembly source file.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited this question several times before posting it. I ended up leaving some irrelevant information in there. And your latter statement is what I've concluded here. Initially I thought ```can't resolve `__text_end__'``` was referring to how it couldn't find the symbol, which I thought was odd given the `-c` operation. But as I was typing this out I realized it was the _operation_ that could not be resolved.

Comment: And so I was wondering if a relocation entry might able able to solve the problem (in the object file result), since at the moment I was only emitting a few sections and relocs was not one of them. So indeed the linker script isn't relevant to the fundamental question.

Comment: You can always create a new linker symbol that computes the difference in the linker script